# Forgot to commit Transaction in hibernate

Tags: performance, spring, hibernate

I am using **hibernate and spring** for my web application.

In this at some places i forgot to commit transaction...like below code

```
 SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
                session = sf.openSession();
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
..........................................Some Code.............................

But forgot to commit transaction.....

finally
{
session.flush();
session.close();
}
```

Now My question is that :-

- Is this creates any problem for me ??
- Any issue regarding memory leak ??
- Increasing load to database??

Or **what is effect of this on my system ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't commit the transaction, then

- The tables involved in the transaction will be locked until the connection gets dropped/closed.
- The changes made to the tables as part of the transaction will be available only for those reusing the same connection from the pool and not to others.
- If `commit()` method is never called on such a connection till it gets closed/dropped, then all the changes made will be lost after close/drop of the connection.

Basically, the behavior of your system will be arbitrary which means it's a problem for you. It doesn't cause any memory leak though.

Comment: @Vidor thanks for reply.when i check my process in machine then it shows so many process in ideal transaction...Is this is the reason behind this??

Comment: No, Idle connections are those connections in the pool that are not actively used by any DB related code. This is not due to transactions not being committed. Once you call `close()` on a connection irrespective of any transactions in it, the connection will be returned to the idle pool.

Comment: @Vidor the third point you describe in your answer that never happened in my case means i never lost any data or changes....

Comment: Possible, provided the same connection is given by the connection pooler to another portion of your code that commits the transactions. But it would be very arbitrary as I already said in the response.

Comment: Just a clarification here.  What happens to uncommitted changes sent to the database when the connection is closed is database dependent.  Oracle JDBC driver, for example, commits such changes.  Every other driver I know of does roll them back.